# Make video not reload after going to a different page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make video not reload after going to a different page? Or another way to have a video as background site wide without reloading in HTML/CSS/JS? or ideally maybe a way to make a site change without the need of adding sub-pages? [simple website closing a menu for example and opening new one?]

Comment: there is no easy solution for that. " easiest" solution includes to save the timestamp of a video to the local storage. Then load the time stamp from the local storage on page load. Alternativly a SPA approach...

Comment: You should reload the necessary part and resources only. Read about [SPA - Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) this technique should be helpful to achieve your goal.